# GroupBy and Select syntax options

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Keeping in view the code below, I want to summarize / group the query results by customer id having sum of the sales and receipts columns next to the customer id column.

```
var sales = from s in context.Sales
            select new { id = s.CustomerID, sales = s.Amount, receipts = (decimal)0 };

var receipts = from r in context.Receipts
            select new { id = r.CustomerID, sales = (decimal)0, receipts = r.Amount };

var summary = sales.Union(receipts).ToList();
```

I tried to achieve the same using some combinations in:

```
var summary = sales.Union(receipts).GroupBy(e=>e.id).Select( ... )
```

... but to no avail.

Looking forward to get the correct relevant syntax.

Comment: 'var summary = sales.Union(receipts).GroupBy(e => e.id).Select(g => new { g. ..... });'

Why can't I get query columns in the member list of IGrouping, the "g" parameter? If I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, although we have to guess what `Select( ... )` contained. You can do this:

```
summary
    .GroupBy(s => s.id)
    .Select(g => new { id = g.Key,
                       salesSum = g.Sum(x => x.sales), 
                       receiptsSum = g.Sum(x => x.receipts)
                     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var salesAndreceipts = from data in context.Receipts
                               join data2 in context.Receipts on data.CustomerID on data2.CustomerID
                               select new { id = r.CustomerID, sales = data.Sales, receipts = data2.Amount };
```

**Update**
Instead of the above, try below after getting the data from the sales and receipts:

```
      var salesAndReceipts = sales.Union(receipts).ToList(); 


        var groupedData = from data in salesAndreceipts
                          group data by new {id=data.CustomerID}
                              into SalesRecepientGroup
                              Select new
                              {
                                  id = SalesRecepientGroup.Key.CustomerID,
                                  sales = SalesRecepientGroup.Sum(x=>x.Sales),
                                  receipts = SalesRecepientGroup.Sum(x=>x.Amount)

                              };
```

Hope this helps.. :)

**Update**

You can then check what queries it is generating under EFProfiler and optimize these.

Comment: Yogiraj! Their is a logical mistake in your salesAndreceipts query, as Sales and Receipts tables have no 1:N relation. In your code it is joining all rows of specific customer from Sales to all rows of specific customer from Receipts.

That's why I have joined both the queries using .Union().